# Tell difference between manual start or by scheduled

Tags: console-application

I am building a console application that will run at night by the windows task scheduler.
Also there should be an option for when the user starts in manually at the middle of the day that the user should parse a datetime with it.

My question: is there some way to tell the difference inside the console app if the application was started manually or by the task scheduler?

Comment: I'd suggest using a simple command line parameter. When starting the application using the task scheduler, provide a parameter `STARTEDBYSCHEDULER` to know that this happened. This is a hack of course, as anybody starting the application manually could just add the argument as well. But if that doesn't concern you, this might be a simple solution.